# Nginx/Gunicorn/python/matlab runtime, Worker failed to boot

Tags: python, matlab, nginx, gunicorn

First, I'm a beginner so bear me please.

I'm trying to deploy a python web app using Nginx/Gunicorn/Python/Matlab, I'm using some packed Matlab libraries (through LibraryCompiler) to be called from python using `import Matlab package` in Python script.

To import Matlab packed libraries I need to install Matlab runtime. After installing Matlab runtime it advises me to set the Matlab runtime path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I added the following line using `nano ~/.bashrc`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v99/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v99/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v99/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v99/extern/bin/glnxa64
```

Without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the bash, trying to import the packed matlab library, it will throw an error `RuntimeError: On Linux, you must set the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to a non-empty string. For more details, see the package documentation.`

after setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it worked perfect locally but when I use `sudo gunicorn3 app:server` it failed to load my python script and it shows the same message as if I didn't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

here it's what appears to me when to trying run my web app.

```
    [2020-12-17 20:48:12 +0000] [29324] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 377, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/hossamedwee/flaskapplication/app.py", line 30, in <module>
    import cyclo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cyclo/__init__.py", line 283, in <module>
    _pir.get_paths_from_os()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cyclo/__init__.py", line 175, in get_paths_from_os
    'For more details, see the package documentation.'))
RuntimeError: On Linux, you must set the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to a non-empty string. For more details, see the package documentation.
```

Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve such a problem by adding this line in my python script.

```
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v99/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v99/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v99/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v99/extern/bin/glnxa64'
```